# section numbering problem

Tags: chapters, section-titles

I don't want to have the III in the section, I  want it to appear in TOC and in the page just 1.section

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eurosym}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{hyperref}
%pour la mise en page des tableaux
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{datetime}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\newdateformat{Monthyeardate}{%
  \monthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR}
  \usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\usepackage[breakable, skins]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{20pt}{40pt}

% Boîte type générique
\newtcolorbox{boitetype}[4][]{enhanced, breakable, before
upper = {\parindent17.6pt}, beforeafter skip =
\baselineskip, colframe = #3, colback = #4, boxrule = 2pt,
arc = 4mm, fonttitle = \bfseries, title = {#2}, coltitle
= black, #1}



\newenvironment{boite}[3][]{\begin{boitetype}[#1]{#2}{#3}{white}}{\end{boitetype}}




\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{
  enhanced,
  attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2ex,xshift=4ex},
  colframe=black,
  colback=white,
  fonttitle=\bfseries, 
  colbacktitle=white,
  coltitle=black,
  boxed title style={
    boxrule=0pt,
    colframe=white,
    },title=#2,
  #1}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} 
\begin{center} 
\includegraphics[width = 0.45\linewidth]{fms.jpg} \\[1.5cm]

\textsc{\LARGE{}Université de médecine ibn el jazzar sousse} \\[1.5cm]
\textsc{\Large{}premier cycle des études médicales} \\[0.5cm] 
\textsc{\large{}Laboratoire d'immunologie} \\[0.5cm] 
\HRule \\[0.6cm]
{\huge\bfseries{}Vue générale du système immunitaire} \\[0.25cm]
\HRule \\[1.5cm]
\Large\textit{rédigé par :} \\
Pr. \textsc{Foued B.Slama} \\[3cm]
\Monthyeardate\large\today \\[2cm] 

\end{center}
\vfill 
\end{titlepage}
\clearpage\setcounter{page}{1}

\begin{huge}
 \chapter*{Objectifs d'apprentissage}
\end{huge}
$-$Définir les 2 types d'immunité


$-$Reconnaitre les caratéristiques de l'immunité innée


$-$Indiquer les éléments constitutifs de l'immunité innée


$-$Identifier les caractéristiques de l'immunité adaptative


$-$Désigner les éléments constituitfs de l'immunité adaptative


$-$Décrire les différentes étapes de la séléction clonale


$-$Expliquer la coopération entre l'immunité humorale et l'immunité adaptative


$-$Différencier immunité humorale et cellulaire


$-$Citer les prinicpales manifestations liées au dysfonctionnement du système immunitaire


\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
    \tableofcontents
    
    

    
    \chapter{Introduction}
   

\begin{mybox}{L'immunologie}
C'est la science qui étudie les moyens de défense de l'organisme.\end{mybox}


$\bullet$ Le système immunitaire \emph{est nécessaire} pour la survie de notre organisme:\\
\begin{itemize}
\item Il protège l'organisme vis-à-vis des agresseurs étrangers, essentiellement les micro-organismes présents dans le milieu qui nous entoure (c'est l'équivalent de l'armée).








\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width = 0.55
\linewidth]{milieu.png}
\caption{Milieu contenant des micro-organismes}
\end{figure}

\item Il protège l'organisme contre les cellules devenues dangereuses, en particulier les cellules cancereuses (c'est l'équivalent de la police).


\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width = 0.55
\linewidth]{globule.jpg}
\caption{Des globules blancs en train de tuer une cellule cancereuse}
\end{figure}
\end{itemize}

\vspace{1cm}


$\bullet$ La protection est divisée en 2 activités :\\
\begin{itemize}

\item \textbf{La reconnaissance:} permet au système immunitaire de distinguer les envahisseurs étrangers des composants du soi.
\item \textbf{La réponse :} La reconnaissance d'un pathogène conduit à une réponse effectrice qui élimine ou neutralise l'organisme étranger.\\
\end{itemize}
$\bullet$ Le système immunitaire agit en produisant une multitude de \emph{cellules} et de \emph{molécules} qui forment un réseau dynamique. Il comporte des \emph{organes lymphoïdes primaires }et des \emph{organes lymphoïdes secondaires }(réaction des cellules immunitaires avec les antigènes étrangers : rate,ganglions...).\\


$\bullet$ L'immunité comprend l'immunité \emph{innée} et l'immunité \emph{adaptative} qui collaborent pour protéger l'organisme.
\vspace{2cm}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width = 0.8
\linewidth]{p4.png}

\end{figure}




\chapter{Historique}
L'histoire de l'immunologie est passée par 5 grandes étapes :\\
\begin{enumerate}
 \item \begin{large}
\underline{Immunité anti-infectieuse :} (immunis=dispensé de)
\end{large}\\


$\bullet$ \emph{Jenner} en $1798$: Inoculation du contenu d'une pustule de vaccine ( variole de la vache) à l'Homme induisant une protection contre la variole.


$\bullet$ \emph{Pasteur} en $1885$: vaccin contre la rage.
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width = 0.35
\linewidth]{jenner.jpg}

\end{figure}

 \item \begin{large}
\underline{Sérologie:}
\end{large}\\


$\bullet$ Découverte des anticorps et du complémént (début du $20^{ème}$ siècle).\\

 \item \begin{large}
\underline{Immunochimie:}
\end{large}\\


$\bullet$ Détermination de la strucutre des immunoglobulines en $1959$.\\


 \item \begin{large}
\underline{Immunologie cellulaire:}
\end{large}\\


$\bullet$ Identification des lymphocytes et distinction entre LB et LT en $1971$.
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width = 0.35
\linewidth]{bl.jpg}

\end{figure}


 \item \begin{large}
\underline{Immunogénétique:}
\end{large}\\


$\bullet$ Découverte des gènes du CMH, des gènes des immunoglobulines et du TCR (entre les années $1970$ et $1980$).




\end{enumerate}



\chapter{L'immunité innée(naturelle)}
\section{Définition:}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The section number is 3 or 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your preamble put:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
```

If you don't want the dot after the number don't put it in the redefinition.

Comment: thank you very much